# Order by association's column maximum value in rails?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Right now my controller has following `index` method (obfuscating real models as `Alpha` and `Beta` for cleanness):

```
def index
  @alphas = Alpha.select('"alphas".*, (SELECT MAX(number) FROM betas WHERE alpha_id = "alphas".id) as max_betas_number')
end
```

The produced SQL is fine and I can even `ORDER BY` the `max_betas_number` column:

```
SELECT "alphas".*, (SELECT MAX(number) FROM betas WHERE alpha_id = "alphas".id) as max_betas_number FROM "alphas" ORDER BY max_betas_number DESC
```

**Question #1:** Is this the right approach?

Although this query works fine as is, until I try to `.paginate()`

Then my whole select gets wrapped in `COUNT()`, producing invalid SQL syntax:

```
SELECT COUNT("alphas".*, (SELECT MAX(number) FROM betas WHERE alpha_id = "alphas".id) as max_betas_number) FROM "alphas" ORDER BY max_betas_number DESC
```

resulting in:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "as"
LINE 1: ...(number) FROM betas WHERE alpha_id = "alphas".id) as max_bet...
                                                             ^
```

**Question #2:** Is this `will_paginate` gem's problem or is this directly dependent on my, say, errorneous `index` method's `.select()`?

Answer (score 0):

Consider **caching** `max_betas_number` inside corresponding `Alpha` model. This will make read queries much simpler (and *probably* faster, depending on amounts of data) **at the cost of an extra write** with each `Beta` modification.

An out-of-the-box ActiveRecord has [`counter_cache` option (see section 4.3.2)](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#has-many-association-reference) on some associations to deal with a **similar situation**: it maintains associated objects' count in a special column in a parent model, something like `<assoc>_count`.